# List comprehension vs for loop ¿Cuál es el error?

Tags: python, loops, if

Realizaba un ejercicio que consistía en utilizar una list comprehension (LC) para sumar los números impares entre 0 y 10. Para ello, se me ocurrió primero utiizar el for loop, analizar su estructura y después pasarlo a una LC. El problema es que al utilizar este for loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    if  i%2 != 0:
        print(sum([i]))
```

No obtuve el resultado deseado, sino solo una lista de números. En cambio, al utilizar LC

```
sum([i for i in range(10) if i%2 !=0])
```

la suma fue correcta. ¿Podría alguien orientarme sobre el error? Soy bastante nuevo en Python y no encuentro ninguna referencia que me ayude a solucionar esta cuestión.
Gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La explicación es muy sencilla.

En tu primer código estás haciendo un loop que va de `0 - 10` y si el numero es impar, entonces imprimes el `sum` del propio numero (por lo que lo imprime sin más)

En el segundo codigo, estás haciendo una lista de números y luego le haces las suma a la lista, por lo que sale el resultado final.

---

En el primer ejemplo deberias guardar los elementos impares en una lista y al acabar el loop, hacer un `sum` para tener el resultado esperado.

```
impares = []
for i in range(10):
    if  i%2 != 0:
        impares.append(i)

print(sum(impares))

>>>25
```

**[Ejemplo online](https://www.ideone.com/Uo7IM2)**